# Reactjs material-ui TextField change color label and underline activity field input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, material-ui

[image]

```
<TextField
    id="standard-full-width"
    label="Password"
    style={{ margin: 8 }}
    fullWidth
    margin="normal"
    placeholder="*******"
/>
```

I'm not able to figure out how to change the color of the label and the underline when the focus is activated on the input field.

Some advice?

Comment: You can check out how to customize the CSS of the textfield in this [Textfield demo](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#customized-inputs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overrule style by supplying them via the `classes` property. I've added an example using the [`makeStyles`](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#hook-api) hook but the property can also be used with classes supplied from the [`withStyles` HOC](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api).

```
import React from "react";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    "& label.Mui-focused": {
      color: "orange"
    },
    "& .MuiInput-underline:after": {
      borderBottomColor: "orange"
    }
  }
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <TextField label="My label" classes={classes} />;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

So, in case you're using a `Component` it will be like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        "& label.Mui-focused": {
          color: "orange"
        },
        "& .MuiInput-underline:after": {
          borderBottomColor: "orange"
        }
    }
})

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <TextField label="My label" classes={this.props.classes} />
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(App)
```

To read up on customizing the TextField component check out these examples: https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#customized-inputs

Comment: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
.....

Comment: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: In the example you make is declared as an App function, the one I use is declared as a class App extends React.Component, because inside I have a state, other methods and render.

Comment: Yep, that's why I said to use the `withStyles` version (and linked to the docs). But I've edited the answer to include example code needed with a Component. Hope this works.

Comment: There is no other way, the problem I already use redux in the project.    export default (LoginComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginComponent));

Comment: It seems to work, but I don't like how it is written: export default (LoginComponent = connect (mapStateToProps) (withStyles (styles) (LoginComponent)));

Comment: You can at least change it to `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withStyles(styles)(LoginComponent))`. It will still be a bit ugly however. The only way to make it look nicer is to split the presentation from the logic. So maybe create an `OrangeTextField` file, use the `withStyles()` in that file and then in this file import `OrangeTextField` and wrap it in `connect()`. That way it will also be easier to re-use the orange textfield. There are many ways to make this nicer, but for functionality this is the way to set it up.

Comment: You could show me an example of how you think it would be more elegant to do it.

A problem that arises is that a field must be normal where it puts the email with the placeholder and the label that then goes up (so what I'm using now the TextField), another where it puts the password must have such graphics ( the last element of the password where it can be shown): https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#input-adornments

Comment: To do the second I have to use not a simple TextField, but FormControl, InputLabel, Input, InputAdornment, IconButton, etc.

Doing it this way, I don't get two fields one below the other in fullWidth mode.

What would you recommend?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean, but take a look at this example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/kind-shadow-xchlo  It will give you an idea of how to separate it a bit. Furthermore you'll just have to figure out what works best for you.

Comment: I'm having the following problem: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `TableHeader`. It was passed a child from ListUserComponent. See ... for more information.
    in WithStyles(WithStyles(ForwardRef(TextField))) (created by ListUserComponent)
    in TableHeader (created by r)

Comment: if I put key in the various components it works, but there is a way that does it automatically?